# Android make activity with tabs and dynamically add views in each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am trying to make an activity have swipable tabs, with each tab having a different fragment (I dont know yet how many fragments I am going to have, so assume they will be at least 5). 
So I am having problems make the parent activity with the tabs (if I said that correctly) and then the fragments themselves have some dynamically added views (text views and one image view) which get their stuff from different async tasks, executed when the fragment is showed.
Don't know if I explained it correctly, but here is my code and I'll ask you please to add in it the needed stuff.

So here is the parrent activity which must host the tabs and the fragments:

```
public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

and here is one of the fragments (the others are similar):

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout layout;
    ImageView iv;
    String anotherURL;
    ArrayList<InfoStuff> ci;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        iv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivPortrait);
        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        ci = b.getParcelableArrayList("infoStuff");
        regionUrl = b.getString("someURL");
        createViews();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void createViews() {

        TextView tv;

        tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setText("le text");
        layout.addView(tv);

        tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setText("some text");
        layout.addView(tv);


        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(v.getApplicationContext()).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        String imgUrl = "someURL";
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgUrl, iv);
    }
}
```

I am also having troubles making the ImageView work, as it is from an additional library (forgot the name, heres the import though import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;)

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention the tabs must be swipeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article [Creating Navigation tabs using TabHost and Fragments in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/) may help you.

> In this article, we will develop an  Android application containing navigation tabs. There are many ways by which we can add navigation tabs to an application.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.0, the standard way to create navigation tab is using action bar. [...]
>
> For Android 2.x and above, we can use Action bar Sherlock library to create navigation library. [...]
>
> In this application, we are creating navigation tabs using TabHost and Fragments.  [...]
>
> This application is developed in Eclipse 3.7.2 with ADT plugin (20.0.2) and Android SDK ( R20.0.1 ) .

Comment: I actually wanted swipeable tabs, sorry forgot to mention that earlier

Comment: Ok Do you Have any idea about viewpager library ?

Comment: these links can help you implemmenting your desired feature i solved my same probelm by using these
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: (Note, I am not flagging this yet since it has the key answer, but...) While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just started doing something very similar to what you want to do. I followed [this tutorial on Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/), which was very helpful in getting the tabs, swiping, and fragments down. (The fragments in this example are just textviews with different colors, but you can easily figure out where to add in your own views).

Hope this helps - it did for me!